# Walking very fast for 30 minutes, twice a day. In which measure is that "aerobic exercise"?

Tags: cardio

I walk every day 30 minutes from my apartment to my office in the morning, and then another 30 minutes back in the evening. I do it at a very fast pace. I would say I walk as fast as one can fast without running (passing people surely think I am late to an important meeting or something, I mean, it is really fast) and I also do it in the weekends.

Out of mere curiosity, I wonder if that can be considered aerobic exercise to a certain extent, and what can be the benefits I should reasonably expect in the long run. My body is fully adapted to that, I sweat very little or nothing at all, and I don't feel tired at all.

I wonder too, if that is enough cardio complement to resistance training, or if ideally I should try to introduce more aerobic exercise (I am 43). I swim from time to time too, but let's forget about it because I don't do it on a regular schedule yet.

Answer (score 3):

Aerobic exercise is measured in heart rate percentage (of max) and time. For instance, we like to say stuff like "I held x% HR for y minutes then z% for w minutes" etc. If either is high, the other is usually low. We can't do high-high without collapsing.

If you don't feel very tired, that's fine. In that case, doing it over a longer time will eventually net you a desirable result. If there are any hills at all in your walks, this is a huge bonus.

And besides, I'm a huge advocate for walking in general. There is a lot to be said for an exercise where you keep a straight back, chin up, and generally good posture for an extended period of time.

Walking for an hour a day is an **amazing** supplement to resistance training.

As for swimming; if you can do it regularly, go for it. It's one of those miracle exercises where you can't really do it wrong. Either way, it's going to be an aerobic exercise with resistance.

But just to strike the point home; you're doing great! Walking is, on its own, a very worthy supplement to resistance training.

Comment: Heart rate is the key measure for sure!

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, your daily walks are aerobic activity (definitely not anaerobic...start farmer's walking that distance, and you'll really get some looks as you pass people).

Just about any by-the-book doctor would applaud your efforts; you're doubling the American Heart Association's recommendation of 150 minutes/week of light-to-moderate aerobic activity.

Is it enough to compliment your resistance training?  Yes, in general terms.  Your light-to-moderate hour/day walks are slowly improving--at least maintaining--your heart's ability to deliver fuel and remove waste from your muscles.  That said, some anaerobic "cardio" every now in then (e.g., interval hill sprints) will improve your muscles' efficiency to use that fuel.

If your aim is to be (or continue being) a generally healthy individual, keep doing what you're doing.  That said, I'd recommend experimenting with some shorter-session, higher intensity training once or twice a week if you can fit it in your schedule; especially if you consider more specific, performance oriented goals in the future.

Comment: +1 for "start farmer's walking that distance, and you'll really get some looks as you pass people". Some really heavy shopping bags might make it look less obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Walking an hour every day is definitely an aerobic exercise

#### *However, it's only good for weightloss and general fitness for beginners.*

***Depending on your goal***, the walk should be an accessory exercise and not your main aerobic exercise. This is because the benefit will diminish after performing this activity for a while. *Thus, you might sweat the first few weeks (or it might take a longer time to reach the destination) but after a while, it becomes relatively easy without getting tired.*

***Unless you introduce some variations in the walk (alternating between running/walking), the benefit will peak.***

I would suggest having a short HIIT session to complement your resistance training. You've already got the low intensity exercise covered. Use short HIIT sessions to complement your resistance training.

Of course, I fully agree with swimming too; it's an awesome exercise worth performing often.

Answer (score 0):

While walking fast for an hour every day is good enough to be very fit compared to people who don't do cardio exercise at all, in your case this is not good enough to even approach the top level cardio fitness that you could obtain. You should add running to your routine; it may take a year or more, but eventually you should be able to run an hour a day.

Comment: I did the C25K program months ago and approached the 40 min, but not *daily*. Are you sure that running *every day* is not dangerous on the knees? It seems to me a bad idea, excepts for those who are under 30 and fit.

Comment: Knee pain can be a problem, you need to see how sensitive you are to that. [This person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cla68) is a bit older than you and he has found a solution that seems to work well for him.